# Is $.browser absent from jquery-migrate?

Tags: javascript, jquery, browser-detection

I have to run someone else's old JS code which is using $.browser. I've search and found a lot of answers like "it's deprecated, use jquery-migrate". So I've included jquery-migrate, however $.browser doesn't seem to exists in that library.
Am I doing something wrong? is there anything special to have that object back
I'd prefer not to mess with the existing code since it's not mine.

TIA

Comment: best bet would likely be to continue loading the old version for the old code rather than using jqmigrate, or updating the old code.

Comment: It was not only deprecated, it was removed.  As [it's webpage](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.browser/) says: _Please try to use feature detection instead._

Comment: OK so I have no choice but changing the old code. Thanks for you answer.

Comment: The doc says "is available only through the jQuery.migrate plugin" so I thought it was still available through the jQuery.migrate plugin but it seems it's not.

Comment: @KevinB: it have been my choice for the last 4 years but at some point the rest of the code should move forward :)

Comment: I mean, you could include two versions of jquery. Sounds terrible, but so does running old out of date code

Comment: Very good point, that will keep things running until I find a replacement. Modernizing a 4 years old framework is a lot of work.

Comment: However they should change the documentation it's misleading.

Answer (score 0):

After more digging I found there is actually **2 versions** of the migrate library, using the "old" one helps keeping an old code running a little longer...